# Unable to remove tomcat7

Tags: apt, tomcat, tomcat7

I am unable to completely remove tomcat7 from my Ubuntu 15.04. I mistakenly deleted its `var/lib/dpkg/info/tomcat7` config file from the file manager. But now when I am trying to delete this package using `apt-get remove` and even through synaptic package manager, I am getting this error:

```
(synaptic:9062): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_child_watch_add_full: assertion 'pid > 0' failed
(Reading database ... 399913 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing tomcat7 (7.0.56-2ubuntu0.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/tomcat7.prerm: 1: /etc/default/tomcat7: Run: not found
dpkg: error processing package tomcat7 (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: tomcat7-common: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 tomcat7 depends on tomcat7-common (>= 7.0.56-2ubuntu0.1).

Removing tomcat7-common (7.0.56-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tomcat7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install. Trying to recover:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused the Package Management System. You should reinstall `tomcat7`, with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall tomcat7
```

Then, when the filesystem contents and the Package Management System agree,

```
sudo apt-get remove tomcat7
```